# Possible to create rippled curtain effect in CSS?

Tags: css

Found this shot on Dribbble: http://dribbble.com/shots/899177-Slide-Concept

What I love about it is that the side bar opens and ripples the main content area on the right hand side, as if it were a blanket or curtains.

I'm just wondering if it is possible to do something like this in CSS? Is it possible to manipulate elements to have a custom rippled effect?

Comment: No. But check this out: http://gyu.que.jp/jscloth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with pure CSS in current browsers. In future browsers you might be able to do it with [Filter Effects](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html).